# How can I add new files to git based on their last modification date?

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

I work locally under Windows. I have a local git repo and already included some files. The folder (and subfolders) where I am working in includes many other files that are not yet tracked and not known to git. Some of these files have not been changed for many months.
I need to add some, but not all of these files. The criterium for inclusion should be the date of last change (e.g. I want to "git add" only files that have been modified within the last month).

Is there a way to do this? Searching help files and threads here only showed me solutions when the files are already tracked.

Comment: Can you explain more about your use case? Typically repositories would fail to compile if some files were missing from version control. Is this more of a historical archive?

Comment: According to the git add documentation, there's no way to do this directly with git add. Sounds like you'll need to create a script or find some way to chain commands, that goes through the files and "git add"-s them one by one based on the date.
On Windows, it might be a Powershell script.

Comment: I use git only locally for version control. In my case, I add version control to an existing folder that includes a lot of "older" files. I selected only a subset and this was no problem for git, as all the other files are just left as "untracked".
But now, I want to include some of these untracked files.

Comment: If you have git bash (or linux subsystem) available, you should be able to run something like `find . -type f -mtime -31 -not -path '*/.git/*' -print -exec git add -- {} +` to add files modified within the last 31 days

Comment: @Jay I think you can make that an answer so OP can accept it, and I assume we can add the bash tag too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible with git only, but if you have "git bash" or WSL available, you should be able to run something like

```
find . -type f -mtime -31 -not -path '*/.git/*' -exec git add -v -- {} +
```

to add files modified within the last 31 days.

Notes:

- If you only want to include certain folders, specify their names instead of `.`
- To list which files are being matched by the specified age,
   run the command without the `-exec` part:
  `find . -type f -mtime -31 -not -path '*/.git/*'`
- To list which files would be added without actually adding them,
  use `git add`'s `--dry-run` option (short: `-n`):
  `find . -type f -mtime -31 -not -path '*/.git/*' -exec git add -v -n -- {} +`

Edit history:

- Instead of `find`'s `-print` expression use `git add`'s `-v` option (a.k.a. `--verbose`). This way only the files that were actually added are listed, not all files that were passed to the `git add` command.
- Add dry-run suggestion to notes